# Image installation files in Windows - Possible?

Tags: windows

I have a range of Windows applications that I currently installing with a Batch script that do the following:

1. Open the executable file
2. Waits for the installation to be processed
3. Begins executing the next file

This is a real pain in the ass. I have to click through ALL of the application settings and so forth.

Is there a way in Windows that I can install all of the applications without clicking through the installation setup?

Can I image a package for all the installation files?

Answer (score 0):

Installer packages usually have a "quiet install" command-line option, but there is no general rule how it's called. [This website lists some of them](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php).

You may also be interested in [Ninite](https://ninite.com/), an automated software installer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this tool and it works wonderful for your requirement:

How to make a project for creating installations for multiple applications
http://www.createinstall.com/help/multi-build-installer.html

You can also write scripts by using following commands to get several apps installed one by one: 
Start-Process "setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/s" -Wait

Batch file can work fine also: 
http://mycomputerforum.com/computer-science/2881-create-batch-file-silent-install-multiple-progams.html